# lenovo IdeaPad-3-14ARE05 Touchpad not working. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Elan Touchscreen"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN0001:00/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800001000003
```

Comment: You are not alone, lenovo managed to screw it up again, i am on ideapad 5 - 14 same shit, manjaro, mint 19.3/20. Switched to windows maybe in one year the drivers will be there. Since I can find my way around in any OS, RMA or windows it is for now. But considering the price of these puppies I'd just wait .

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1883243

Comment: Hi! The workaround presented here https://askubuntu.com/a/1250962/1099964 works on my IdeaPad-3 14ARE05!
But the brightness keys are still not working with ubuntu 20.04 LTS - do they work for you?

Answer (score 6):

If you use kernel 5.8 or newer your can try:

1. Open terminal
2. Login with `root` (on debian  `su -l`, on Ubuntu `sudo su`)
3. Edit file `/etc/default/grub`
4. Replace line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nocrs quiet splash"`
5. Save file `/etc/default/grub`
6. Execute `update-grub`
7. Reboot

This has been tested on Debian bullseye and Ubuntu Focal on Ideapad 3 15iil30.
With bullseye on an ideapad 3, everything is functional, mouse, touchpad, video, sound, webcam, bluetouth, etc.

Comment: this method activated my touchpad. However, it turned off my wi-fi adapter)))

Comment: Worked on Ideapad 3 14IIL05 and Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

As I cannot say this is a duplicate of this question:

I will add the answer of @theunreal89 here for future reference. (I don't think good answers should be in the comments)

It seems not to be possible to blacklist `elants_i2c` driver, as it is a built-in kernel module for Ubuntu:

```
stefano@stefano-IdeaPad-5-15ARE05:~$ modinfo elants-i2c
name:           elants_i2c
filename:       (builtin)
license:        GPL
description:    Elan I2c Touchscreen driver
author:         Scott Liu <scott.liu@emc.com.tw>
```

so there is a faster way than compiling the kernel. Just create a SystemD unit like the below:

```
stefano@stefano-IdeaPad-5-15ARE05:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/touchpadfix.service 
[Unit]
Description=Fix touchpad issue by binding correct driver

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/touchpadfix
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and create `/usr/local/bin/touchpadfix` file as follows

```
stefano@stefano-IdeaPad-5-15ARE05:~$ cat  /usr/local/bin/touchpadfix
#!/bin/bash
modprobe i2c_hid
echo "i2c-ELAN0001:00" > /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/elants_i2c/unbind
echo "i2c-ELAN0001:00" > /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/i2c_hid/bind
```

and then make it executable, enable and start the unit with the following commands:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/touchpadfix
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable --now touchpadfix.service
```

and touchpad should start to work immediately!

SOURCE: [IdeaPad 5 15are05 - elan touchpad not working on 20.04 nor on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248176/ideapad-5-15are05-elan-touchpad-not-working-on-20-04-nor-on-18-04/1250962#1250962) and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_IdeaPad_5_15are0 which is giving us unbind-bind fix and **dl3it** user on this post https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207759#c17

Comment: This workaround is for 15ARE05 only. The 14ARE05 touchpad is completely different and this fix won't work, even though the 15ARE05 has quite similar symptoms.

Comment: Works perfectly on 15ARE05 when `pci=nocrs` in grub did absolutely nothing.  Giving full instructions on how to set up as a systemd unit are just icing on the cake.  This is brilliant, thank you so much!!!

Comment: this worked for me on 15ARE05. Thanks a lot!

Comment: After some time passed, I noticed that my Wi-Fi connection some times being lost. Is it possible that touchpadfix somehow affected my wi-fi adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade OS to version 21.04 solves this problem.

Comment: Upgrading to a non-LTS version may not always be a desired option.

Comment: Maciej Brzezny - I agree. After an upgrade to 21.04 touchpad works just as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading did not solely fix the issue on this IdeaPad 3. Following the first step worked after upgrade and running on kernel 5.11.0-37-generic

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` as root, e.g.

```
sudoedit /etc/default/grub
```

Replace the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nocrs quiet splash"
```

Save the file and exit.

Execute

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot