# Ubuntu 20.04 touchpad doesn't work on new Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: drivers, 20.04, touchpad, lenovo

I have just bought a new Lenovo laptop. I've installed the Ubuntu 20.04, but my touchpad doesn't work.

Here is the result of `xinput` command:

[image: output of xinput]

Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: A little more info will be required. Which Lenovo do you have? They make a lot of devices. You had mentioned that you've tried many things, but could you outline some of the fixes you've tried that have failed? This will allow someone to offer a possible solution that you have not tried that will work for you specific Lenovo 

Answer (score 0):

1. $xinput shows the available input devices in the machine. but, the machine hava a data for it. So,Maybe it is hardware(touchpad) problem.
2. Maybe Hardware is good,just reboot and try any other OS.
3. else, see the settings for touchpad(Settings > mouse and touchpad> touchpad) is enable/disable. Many lenovo laptop's F6(function key) for enable or disable touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Lenovo t420 that has touchpad problems. I run this script at startup:

```
DEVICENUM=$(xinput | grep SynPS/2 | grep 'id=' |  cut -d= -f2 | cut -b 1,2)
printf "\033c"
xinput set-prop $DEVICENUM "Device Enabled" 0
xinput set-prop $DEVICENUM "Device Enabled" 1
echo "done"
```

Comment: do you have to run this everytime?

Comment: I run in at startup with a chron, yes.

Comment: That is strange because I had a T420 Thinkpad and never had issues with the touchpad but now with an Ideapad the touchpad is not even recognized.

Answer (score 0):

sudo gedit file /etc/default/grub

```
Replace line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nocrs quiet splash"

Save file /etc/default/grub

Execute update-grub

Reboot
```

As it's commented here

[lenovo IdeaPad-3-14ARE05 Touchpad not working. Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249298/lenovo-ideapad-3-14are05-touchpad-not-working-ubuntu-20-04)

It works for me on 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and I have faced the same problem. My touchpad was not working after changing my OS from Windows 11 to Ubuntu 20.04/18.04. In Settings, only the mouse options were visible, not the touchpad ones.

If the problem is with your hardware, you must visit the nearby customer care service. If it's not a hardware issue, then there is no problem with your drivers also.

All you need to do is just make a small change on your default `/etc/default/grub` file. That's how I resolved the problem. Follow these steps:

1. Open a terminal.
2. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo gedit file /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. The `/etc/default/grub` text file will be opened. If it is empty, navigate to its adjacent tab.
4. Replace the line:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   with:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="pci=nocrs quiet splash"
   ```
5. Click on *Save* and return to the terminal.
6. Run the following command:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
7. Reboot.

Your issue will be resolved. Your touchpad will be working.