# Function keys and touchpad Lenovo Ideapad S145 15IIL

Tags: touchpad, function-keys

for some reason some function keys, like enable/disable touchpad and brightness just don't work. The touchpad is not working, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the touchpad, the fix is here:

[lenovo IdeaPad-3-14ARE05 Touchpad not working. Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249298/lenovo-ideapad-3-14are05-touchpad-not-working-ubuntu-20-04)

Function keys work except for brightness