# Touchpad not working on Lenovo Ideapad 3 after fresh install (Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

So, as my username suggests I'm noob at this. I was running Ubuntu just fine on another laptop and this is the first major issue I have been unable to solve myself with a bit of googling.

I have tried the suggestions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249298/lenovo-ideapad-3-14are05-touchpad-not-working-ubuntu-20-04) which result in errors when rebooting:

[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTlwD.jpg)

I also tried GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs quiet splash"

After a reinstall and editing /etc/default/grub once again, I am no longer receiving the error above, but the touchpad is still not working. Here are some images including what /etc/default/grub looks like, output from sudo grub-update and xinput:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEzi6.jpg

I cannot use screenshots as I don't have a mouse for this device and find it difficult to navigate using only the keyboard. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in kernel v5.15: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970056

To solve this issue, upgrade your kernel version to `v5.18` from mainline or look for tutorials online how to do that. Its really simple. Kernel `v5.18` has no such problems.

However, it's not known how much time it will take to fix this in kernel version coming in ubuntu 22.04 which is v5.15

Another post: [Ubuntu 22.04 LTS have problem with grub configs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412475/ubuntu-22-04-lts-have-problem-with-grub-configs/1413284#1413284)

Comment: I have a fresh install of 22.04 with Lenovo touchpad not working, and upgraded to 5.18, but touchpad still does not work. Is there more to it than a kernel upgrade?

Comment: Same here. This didn't help. What else should I do to make it work?