# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS have problem with grub configs

Tags: boot, grub2, touchpad, elantech

I have installed Ubuntu many times, after which my touchpad would not work (Lenove idepad s145) and I've entered that command:GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs" and my touchpad worked but in  22.04 In LTS this does not work. Fsck error and not logged in.I've tried many times by reinstalling Ubuntu.Please can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in kernel v5.15: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1970056

To solve this issue, upgrade your kernel version to `v5.18` from mainline or look for tutorials online how to do that. Its really simple. Kernel `v5.18` has no such problems.

However, it's not known how much time it will take to fix this in kernel version coming in ubuntu 22.04 which is v5.15