# Touchpad drivers

Tags: touchpad

[IdeaPad 5 15are05 - elan touchpad not working on 20.04 nor on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248176/ideapad-5-15are05-elan-touchpad-not-working-on-20-04-nor-on-18-04)

Everything exectued well but after kernel update 5.7.2 it results blank screen on restart.

I have to boot in old kernel to work

I need only touchpad driver for Lenovo IPS S340. It was working till i partitioned later didnt work. Installed os with ubuntu 20.04amd64.iso

Help pls

Comment: it would be helpful to find more information about the type / brand / make / errormessages related to this touchpad! do not expect anyone to find out the touchpad you have by naming the Lenovo model . If it is an ELAN you may try  "modprobe i2c_hid", have a look if it works.