# Ubuntu 20 not starting and showing below photo when i choose ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, restart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVsMj.jpg)

I was updating Ubuntu software, but accidentally laptop shutdown cause of low battery, next day when i select Ubuntu =open.. Then it shows this picture... Please help!! I need to complete my assignment

Comment: What you have is known as [kernel panic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35722/what-is-kernel-panic)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix or remove a broken kernel (Ubuntu 20.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253247/how-to-fix-or-remove-a-broken-kernel-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: Please clarify your release; your title says 20 which implies a *snap* only system such as Ubuntu Core 20, but you also tagged 20.04 which is a *deb* based system and thus a different product. Ubuntu has used *yy* format releases for *snap* only products since 2016 (all *deb* based systems are *year.month* in format).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Answer (score 0):

A sudden power off can cause great damage if it happens on the wrong split second. You will probably need to reinstall (I may get downvotes for stating this, but it is imho the truth, inconvenient as it sounds). Even if you could recover with just a file system check, corrupt user and system files may remain.

- Startup the computer with a live DVD or USB.
- First of all, copy the most recent version of your assignment (and all of your user files) to a backup medium. To achieve this, you will need, in the live environment, to click the partition in the left pane of the file manager in order to mount. Then navigate to "home", then the folder that has the same name as your login to find your user files.
- Subsequently, once your personal files are safe, the easiest and quickest way would be a reinstall where you erase your existing installation. That will erase all files on the drive.

It is also possible to reinstall *without* loosing files. However, that is a technically more complicated solution, so I do not recommend that to novice users. In the installer, you can select "Something else". Then, you need to assign the installation partition yourself. The trick is to *uncheck* the format checkbox. That way, the installer will not erase the partition, but just rewrite all system files, preserving your user data, user configuration and all applications you manually installed. Before doing that, you will need to check and repair the file system.

Whatever you do, make sure you have an up to date backup of your user files. Even with methods where data are preserved, there remains a risk that the data will be lost due to a human or technical error.