# What's the best way to re-install damaged kernel from USB stick Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, kernel

I have an existing Ubuntu 20.04 filesystem which I can no longer boot from.  I would like repair it rather than do a full re-install because there are home directories and a bunch of additional software tools which I would like to preserve.

I can boot from a USB stick and fsck and mount the filesystem.  The /boot directory is missing some files.  What is the best way to go about re-installing the kernel itself from the Ubuntu running on the USB stick?

Is there some way to tell apt or dpkg that the installation goes into the mounted filesystem rather than the current root?

What packages should I ask for?  Offhand, I'm guessing linux-image, linux-headers, linux-hwe, linux-modules.  What else?

Comment: All tho, this will be the default answer for most boot problems, check out boot repair https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair/

Comment: also look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/1253247/ddg#1253346

Comment: But how do I tell apt or dpkg that I want it to install in /mnt/boot and not in /boot?

Comment: do `sudo chroot <path to the root directory of the computer>` that will make all programs think that the dir is the root dir type `exit` when you are done