# Kernelpanic with latest installed kernel on Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel

My laptop goes directly into kernel panic at first startup every time I try to start it. Long pressing the power button to shut it down and starting it up again, takes me to the grub menu where I have to select the second latest installed kernel, as the latest one seems broken.

```
OS Version: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa)
Kernel Version (Broken): linux-generic 5.15.0-46
Kernel Version (Working): linux-generic 5.15.0-41
```

I tried following [this "tutorial"](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253346) but with no success. The file "initrd.img-5.15.0-46" didn't exist in my boot directory and the command `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-generic` failed with the following output and I didn't proceed further:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
8 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for linux-generic:amd64
```

When trying to update my system or execute `sudo apt install linux-generic` the update/command fails as well with [this output](https://pastebin.com/pGj41DfB)

I have some Linux knowledge, but I never did anything regarding kernels/boot apart from dual-boot setups, so I'm a complete noob regarding kernel problems and fixing them. Does anyone of you have some tips or a solution for my issue?

Edit: As also written in an answer to [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/a/1427151/1628400), the issue seems to be this line in the output in particular:

`installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1`

Which then causes the following processes to fail as well. How can I fix this?

**Fix:**
I think I found a solution on [this page](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/). I removed the files of all packages which post install scripts fail. After executing `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` a last time, the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution on [this page](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/). I removed the files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` of all packages which post install scripts failed. After executing `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` a last time, the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to install the latest HWE kernel in a "hacky" way, instead of just installing it with the normal package. It also seems you somehow ended in a situation with partially installed packages.

The normal way of installing the HWE kernel line on Ubuntu 20.04 would be this:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
```

This should install the kernel 5.15.0-46-generic on your 20.04 without any hassle.

If you have problems, you can try different steps [as indicated here](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/).

###### 1. Reconfigure package database:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

###### 2. Reinstall or force install: (in this case `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04`)

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
```

or

```
sudo apt install -f linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
```

###### 3. Remove troublesome packages: (in this case `linux-firmware`)

```
sudo apt remove linux-firmware
```

###### 4. Remove files of troublesome packages: (in this case `linux-firmware`)

```
sudo apt mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-firmware* /tmp
```

There are also endless threads here about fixing broken packages - try and take a look at them first.

Comment: The `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command fails with [this output](https://pastebin.com/Cz5gyijL). As it seems, it fails because of this: `installed linux-firmware package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-firmware`? Be aware that fixing dependency problems can be a bit of trial-and-error..

Comment: The command fails with the following output:
_i don't know how to format code properly in here. So here's the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/WAZjhn3S_

Comment: I think I fixed it. See the bottom of the original question for more info

Comment: I've included those solutions to my post.