# Ideapad 5 15are05 - Touchpad No Longer Working

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, lenovo, ideapad

Running Linux Kernel 5.7.4 with Ubuntu 20.04 on Ideapad 5 15ARE05.

The touchpad for this laptop did not work out of the box on Ubuntu, but after a lot of searching, I found a working solution here: [IdeaPad 5 15are05 - elan touchpad not working on 20.04 nor on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248176/ideapad-5-15are05-elan-touchpad-not-working-on-20-04-nor-on-18-04) by blacklisting the `elants 12c` driver. However, yesterday the touchpad completely stopped working and no longer even shows up in `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`.

Using the solution provided by *theunreal89*:

```
modprobe i2c_hid
echo "i2c-ELAN0001:00" > /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/elants_i2c/unbind
echo "i2c-ELAN0001:00" > /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/i2c_hid/bind
```

I get the error that `Module elants-12c not found` along with `no such device`. It is almost as if the touchpad just disappeared overnight! If anybody could help me with this, I would really, really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try restart? There could have been some error while waking up from sleep for example.

Comment: @lamka02sk Yes, restarting sometimes temporarily solves the problem, but a more reliable solution is needed.

Comment: Then you should really just try to recompile the kernel. That's what I did and everything works flawlessly. My first time ever compiling Linux kernel and everything worked out just fine. I followed answer from the same question you did: https://askubuntu.com/a/1248439/543371, but I had replace the last 3 commands with this answer since I was compiling on a different machine: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/531901. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have a laptop Ideapad 3 15are05. And my touchpad didn't work either, used the same as you did. The command helped me to solve the problem: `echo -n 1-7:1.0 | tee -a unbind`