# Lenovo touchpad not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, kernel, touchpad, lenovo

I recently switched to Ubuntu 20.04 dual boot with windows on my device model lenovo ideapad slim 3i, touchpad is working fine on windows but its not working on ubuntu

xinput -

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver Mouse                 id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver Consumer Control      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver                       id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver System Control        id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Compx 2.4G Receiver Consumer Control      id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I found a similar problem at [IdeaPad 5 15are05 - elan touchpad not working on 20.04 nor on 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248176/ideapad-5-15are05-elan-touchpad-not-working-on-20-04-nor-on-18-04) and i followed instructions but i am getting an error when using command **sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.10.20** as

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.20
W: missing /lib/modules/5.10.20
W: Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/5.10.20: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
cat: /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_hiMLs1/lib/modules/5.10.20/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
find: ‘/var/tmp/mkinitramfs_hiMLs1/lib/modules/5.10.20/kernel’: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_hiMLs1/lib/modules/5.10.20: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_hiMLs1/lib/modules/5.10.20: No such file or directory
```

I tried a lot but i am unable to find a solution to it.

Comment: Which kernel is on your machine? Unless you have 5.10.20 installed — the `-k` value you’ve specified — the sources required will not be present. Change the `-k` value to a kernel that is present 

Comment: Try https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity. Caution: USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.